# Possible to use page on external site as content for MailChimp?

Tags: templates, mailchimp, newsletter

We've got a WordPress site and I've built a page that pulls from different sections of our site which I'd like to use as the content for a bi-weekly MailChimp newsletter. Is there anyway to automate pulling in a div on our site into the body of a MailChimp template?

All the tools I've found pull in the page as "an article" and just put an image and headline into the message body, rather than the full page verbatim.

Not adverse to doing some coding, but not sure how to start.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two different routes you might be able to try. The first is to generate an RSS feed for the content you're talking about and then use an [RSS Campaign](http://mailchimp.com/features/rss-to-email/) to send the email. Depending on how you have this data stored on your site, WordPress might already be generating an RSS feed for you for that content.

The second option involves more coding. If you create a template with an [editable section](http://templates.mailchimp.com/getting-started/template-language/) you can then pass in the content of that section [via the API](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/campaigns/update.php). This is probably harder, since the campaign content APIs are pretty convoluted in v2.0. v3.0 should make that easier, but it's [still in beta](https://github.com/mailchimp/APIv3-examples/wiki).